# Building Yocto linux image - "bitbake image-full" error

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build the Yocto linux image. I am following the process given in Sergey's Blog. Unzip the file:

```
$ 7z x Board_Support_Package_Sources_for_Intel_Quark_v0.7.5.7z
```

Unzip meta-clanton_v0.7.5.tar.gz:

```
$ tar xzvf Board_Support_Package_Sources_for_Intel_Quark_v0.7.5/meta-clanton_v0.7.5.tar.gz
```

Change directory to meta-clanton_v0.7.5:

```
$ cd meta-clanton_v0.7.5
```

Run setup.sh:

```
$ ./setup.sh
```

Source poky/oe-init-build-env script, giving it the build directory (yocto_build) as a parameter:

```
$ source poky/oe-init-build-env yocto_build
```

Run bitbake to build the image:

```
$ bitbake image-full
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bitbake", line 275, in <module>
    ret = main()
  File "/usr/bin/bitbake", line 222, in main
    bb.msg.init_msgconfig(configuration.verbose, configuration.debug,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init_msgconfig'
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea why do you need full Yocto image, but in case you don't need it you may build your own kernel for Intel Quark and, for example, Buildroot helps you with root file system.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the 0.7.5 version, so I've tried this on the 1.0.0 version.

Extracting meta-clanton-v1.0.0.tar.gz

```
cd meta-clanton_v1.0.0
./setup.sh
. poky/oe-init-build-env yocto_build
bitbake image-full -e
```

Running `bitbake image-full` does also start the build without any issue. (I haven't let it complete though.)

I'm slightly worried about your traceback, which includes `"/usr/bin/bitbake"`. If you have installed a bitbake package on your build-machine, please uninstall it. The poky-git repo does include it's own copy of bitbake, which will ensure that you're the version of bitbake you're using is compatible with the rest of your meta-data.

(I'd also suggest updating to the latest meta-clanton release).